# numpy least-squares solution for a matrix with complex elements

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I am trying to solve the equation y=a*x. I have three measurements for x (x1,x2,x3) and y (y1,y2,y3) and am trying to find "a" ( the slop). The first important thing is that y and X are complex numbers (e.g., a+ib). When I divide y1/x1 and the rest of the data, I get the correct answer (I already know the answer), but when I  use the np.linalg.lstsq(), I get different one.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
y1= -19.64927911-6.1398258j
x1=-1.1754612296645994+1.246124677990216*1j
y2=-(20.362010267083804+5.457126922032681*1j)
x2=-1.1754612296645994+1.246124677990216*1j
y3=-(-21.582640711300716-4.866985215398231*1j)
x3=1.0043723963072644-0.6003393298974578*1j
coeff_1=y1/x1
coeff_2=y2/x2
coeff_3=y3/x3

########linear least square method
X=np.vstack((x1,x2,x3))
Y=np.vstack((y1,y2,y3))

[coeff, resid, _, singular_values] = np.linalg.lstsq(X, Y, rcond=None)
print(coeff_1)
print(coeff_2)
print(coeff_3)
print(coeff)
print(np.abs(coeff_1))
print(np.abs(coeff_2))
print(np.abs(coeff_3))
print(np.abs(coeff))
```

If you run it, coeff_1 is different from coeff_2 (which is incorrect). Please help me figure this out.

Comment: y1/x1 has the opposite sign to y2/x2. So there is not a fixed slope for your data. Is there maybe a sign error in your data?
y3/x3 gives a completely different value. So why should lstsq give the solution of y1/x1 ? lstsq() gives the value that fits best for your data, somewhere between y1/x1, y2/x2 and y3/x3.

Answer (score 1):

I visualized the (complex) values `y1/x1`, `y2/x2` and `y3/x3` and the fitted coeficient from your data:

```py
plt.plot((y1/x1).real, (y1/x1).imag, marker = 'o', label = 'y1/x1')
plt.plot((y2/x2).real, (y2/x2).imag, marker = 'o', label = 'y2/x2')
plt.plot((y3/x3).real, (y3/x3).imag, marker = 'o', label = 'y3/x3')
plt.plot(coeff.real, coeff.imag, marker = 'o', label = 'lstsq-fit')
plt.xlabel('real')
plt.ylabel('imag')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Visualization of data]

Your data varies wildly. Why should a least-square-fit with that data give exactly the value `y1/x1` ? The leastsquare-fit seems to be nice in the middle of your data.

Comment: I don't know how least squares work for complex numbers. I thought it would plot the best line fitting the points and find the slope of the fitting line!!

Comment: The method of least squares is a method we can use to find the regression line that best fits a given dataset. We can use the linalg. lstsq() function in NumPy to perform least squares fitting.

Comment: numpy.linalg.lstsq() works the same for real as for complex numbers by finding the value a that minimizes the sum of squared deviations between a*x and y. So yes, it basically fits a line through the data and gives the slope. But even with real values, if you have (x,y) data points, the slope is not exactly y1/x1 but something that works best for all values. Compare the plot in the numpy-documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: Mind that we cannot easily visualize this "line through the data" as this would require a 4D-plot (2D values for x and 2D values for y). So while I plotted the different values for y/x, do not confuse this with the typical 2D plot for real values with the regression line through it!

Comment: I just know that this has been used in a function and I kind of know that the absolute value of the slope should be something close to the abs(y1/x1), abs(y2/x2) and abs(y3/x3). The difference between y1/x1 , y2/x2 and y3/x3 comes from the measurements error.

Comment: As you are fitting to the complex data, the negative and positive (real and imaginary) data is canceling each other out partially, leading to a relative low absolute value of the coefficient from the fit compared to individual x/y pairs. It is like getting the mean of -100 and +120 and expecting a value that has also a large absolute value.
If your relevant data is the absolute values, you should fit to that and maybe just get the mean of the absolute values of your y_i / x_i data.